# Auto Increment in child model

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class Pallet_Mission(models.Model):
code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
load_type = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)
mission_no = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True,blank=True)

class PalletSubMission(models.Model):
mission_id = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
pallet_mission = models.ForeignKey(Pallet_Mission,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='sub',null = True)
point = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
```

i have a parent and child model look like this. and my output look something like this

```
        "code": 52,
        "mission_no": "test1234",
        "load_type": "1234",
        "sub": [
            {
                "id": 75,
                "mission_id": "s1",
                "point": null,
   
                "pallet_mission": 52
            },
            {
                "id": 76,
                "mission_id": "s2",
                "point": null,
                "pallet_mission": 52
      
            }
        ],

    }
```

Now my 'mission_id" are inserted manually.
I want my child model's "mission_id" to be like auto increment like shows 's1' for the first data 's2' for the second data and so on .But it will reset in another set of data like for data "code":53 the 1st data in "sub" will start again with 's1'. Not sure if it is auto increment, how can i do it?

serializers.py

```
class PalletSubSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
class Meta:
    model = PalletSubMission
    fields = '__all__'

class Pallet_Mission_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
sub = PalletSubSerializers(many=True)
class Meta:
    model = Pallet_Mission
    fields = '__all__'

def create(self, validated_data):
    sub = validated_data.pop('sub')
    mission = Pallet_Mission.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for i in sub:
        PalletSubMission.objects.create(pallet_mission=mission,**i)
    
    return mission

def update(self,instance,validated_data):
    sub =validated_data.pop('sub')
    instance.load_type=validated_data.get('load_type',instance.load_type)
    instance.mission_no=validated_data.get('mission_no',instance.mission_no)
    
    instance.save()
    sub_mission = PalletSubMission.objects.filter(pallet_mission=instance.pk).values_list('id', flat=True)
    sub_mission_list =[]
    for i in sub:
        if "id" in i.keys():
            if PalletSubMission.objects.filter(id=i['id']).exists():
                sub_instance = PalletSubMission.objects.get(id=i['id'])
                sub_instance.mission_id = i.get('mission_id',sub_instance.mission_id)
                sub_instance.point = i.get('point',sub_instance.point)
             
                sub_instance.save()
                sub_mission_list.append(sub_instance.id)
            else:
                continue
        else:
            sub_instance = PalletSubMission.objects.create(pallet_mission=instance,**i)
            sub_mission_list.append(sub_instance.id)

    for i in sub_mission:
        if i not in sub_mission_list:
            PalletSubMission.objects.filter(pk=i).delete()
    return instance
```

Comment: Plz put your serializers code

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve those things using overriding `save()` method like this

#### models.py

```
    class Pallet_Mission(models.Model):
          code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
          load_type = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)
          mission_no = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True,blank=True)
    
          def __str__(self):
                return self.load_type
    
    class PalletSubMission(models.Model):
          mission_id = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True,unique=True)
          pallet_mission = models.ForeignKey(Pallet_Mission,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='sub',null = True)
          point = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
    
    
          def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
                count_obj = PalletSubMission.objects.all().count()+1
                self.mission_id = f's{count_obj}'
                super(PalletSubMission, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

#### Output Admin Panel

[image]

Comment: i tried this way but it doesnt reset back to s1 when u add another pallet_mission in my case. like ur 1st pallet_mission got 3 sub mission it count to s3 ,but when another pallet_mission comes in it start with s4. i want it to start with s1 again for each pallet_mission